# Should I use strata(), cluster() or frailty() to account for center specific characteristic in a time-varying analysis

Tags: clustering, time-varying-covariate, stratification

The research question revolves around whether a time-varying intervention at a center enhances the transplantation hazard per person. I have patient-level data and I need to account for the center transplant volume. I believe adjusting for the center transplant volume is inappropriate, as it is in the pathway of the event and functions more as a mediator than a confounder. To address transplant volume per center and also, specific practices in each hospital in the analysis, I was planning to conduct the analysis with clustering, as follows:

**mod1 = coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, status)~int.tv,
cluster = center_code,
data = dat)**

But I am not sure if it would be more appropriate to use **strata()** instead as follows:

**mod2 = coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, status)~int.tv+strata(center_code),
data = dat)**

What do you think would be the correct approach here? also what would be the difference in the interpretation? there is also a **flailty()** term that could be considered, but I am not understanding the differences between all these terms.

**mod2 = coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, status)~int.tv+frailty(center_code),
data = dat)**

Comment: You might be overthinking the possibilities here. Cluster seems to me to be the most natural. Frailty doesn't seem helpful since it is usually a quality that varies among individuals and only incidentally across centers.

Answer (score 1):

Any of those could be reasonable choices, depending on what you want to evaluate.

The `strata()` choice allows for different baseline hazards among the values of `center_code`, but doesn't impose any further structure related to `center_code` or allow comparisons among centers.

The `cluster()` and `frailty()` choices are of marginal and conditional (mixed-effect) models, respectively. Section 9.2 of [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842) puts the distinction between them this way, in the context of a study using litters of rats:

> The marginal [cluster] model estimates the population averaged relative risk due to treatment; that is, the risk of a random sample of treated rats relative to a random sample of untreated, and the frailty model estimates the relative risk within litters.

The `cluster()` term provides the same point estimates of coefficients as would the model without it; the standard errors are adjusted to take within-center correlations into account. The `frailty()` term imposes a particular distribution (gamma, gaussian or t) of random effects among centers. The [`coxme` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=coxme) allows for more complex Gaussian random effects; it might allow you to evaluate `int.tv` as a random effect among centers.

If there are only a few values of `center_code`, you might consider treating it as a fixed effect, and perhaps including an interaction between `center_code` and `int.tv` to evaluate differences among centers directly, around a shared baseline hazard.